# imgの高さを取得したい

Tags: javascript, html, css

htmlの高さが決まっていない(可変)要素の高さを取得したいのですが、取得方法が分かりません。
以下のリンクを参考にしてスライドショーを作りました。
https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/417216/
現状ではスライドショーの下に他の要素が入り込んでしまいます。
ご教示いただければ幸いです。

```js
function slideSwitch() {
  var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');

  if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow img:last');

  var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow img:first');

  $active.addClass('last-active');

  $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
  setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3000 );
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


#slideshow {
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
}

#slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

#slideshow img.active {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#slideshow img.last-active {
  z-index: 9;
}

/*----------top----------*/
.top-bk-img {
  background-image:url("../images/webbase03-04-0609.png");
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="top" class="container">
  <div id="slideshow">
  <img src="images/web-base01.png" alt="画像1" class="active">
  <img src="images/web-base02.png" alt="画像2">
</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bk-img"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

element.style.heightでページロード時に取得することができました。
もう解決済みです。